# Warning while trying to submit app to appstore : Application failed codesign check

Tags: iphone, app-store

I keep getting the same warning again and again.After googling and reading lots of posts in stackoverflow and other communities i found lots of people encountering the same problem while trying to upload their app to appstore.

*This is the only warning im getting.

**I found no precise solution for solving this problem.I am not able to locate the source of this problem.**

Here is the warning:

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/MacMini_02/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/####-chqadngrerizjhferrtytxmcuxxl/ArchiveIntermediates/####/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/        ####.app/####
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/MacMini_02/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/#####-chqadngrerizjhferrtytxmcuxxl/ArchiveIntermediates/####/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/#####.app: valid  on disk
/Users/MacMini_02/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/#####-chqadngrerizjhferrtytxmcuxxl/ArchiveIntermediates/####/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/####.app:         satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)
```

I have followed the normal checklist routine suggested in other posts.(Still i get the warning)

1. Have selected the correct distribution certs and provisioning
   profiles.(I have removed all my other developer cert from my keychain to avoid ambiguities )
2. Checked the same in keychain access.(Deleted and downloaded the distribution certs and prov profiles more than 10 times :-(  )
3. Added a duplicate scheme for release as Distribution
4. Set the build configuration in Edit Scheme as Distribution in
   Archive tab and am running it in iOS Device mode.
5. Deleted the build and archive files,cleaned  and restarted xcode several
   times.
6. I have even  created new projects and moved my code hoping that it would reolve the issue

Have wasted lots of time in this warning :-(

**Am i missing any other significant step???**

**I am sure that the distribution cert and prov profile that i am using are valid.**

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

It would be great if u could identify the problem and provide me the solution(step b step) or direct me to a site where it explains the procedure for the same step by step/video(so that i dont miss out on anything)..

Comment: Did you select the right signing identity for both the Target(s) and the Project build settings?

Comment: yes..i have selected the correct signing identity

Comment: @Mr.Anonymous: Please check my answer.  Apple had some problems with certificates, and they just fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and finally resorted to raising a request with Apple.  The response was that it was occuring with an early release of xcode 4 and that down loading the latest release of xcode 4 would fix the problem.

For an existing app, Apple advise create a new project in the latest version of xcode 4 and copy you files into it.  I haven't had a lot of time to experiment, so I have been creating my new projects in xcode 3.6 and migrating them across which seems to work.

Comment: Hey i am currently using the following Xcode version.. Xcode 4.2 (4C177).. i think is the latest version of Xcode as i am not able to update it further.. Should i uninstall it?? Which version is the best when consideing the app submission scenarios

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty confident about certificate and provisioning profile, then try to revoke your certificate and recreate everything new appId, new Provisioing for new certificate and then try again. i was encountering similar problem but i was getting error after uploading the binary.

hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely positive you've done the right steps, try downloading and building this tool below for checking for certificate errors:

https://github.com/karstenBriksoft/CertificateHelper

Or just download  a pre-built copy [here](http://cl.ly/DNz2).

Give a shot and see if it can help you spot a small mistake in your certificates.

---

Edit: This could be your problem.  Here's what Apple just stated:

> We have identified and resolved a recent issue with certificates for
>   iOS and Mac code signing, Apple Push Notifications and Safari
>   Extensions. If you have experienced any problems with a certificate
>   issued over the past 4 days, simply re-generate a new one.

So, try creating a new certificate.